# ASPDOTNetCORE 6 function app throwing IConfigurationBuilder not found error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created CosmosDBTrigger funtion app in ASPDOTNETCORE 6.0.
While running the function it is throwing below error.

> [2023-01-1T12:39:13.733Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 'f94afi4a-2430-47e6-a43b-e7e1aufe6bcd'.
> Engagements.Function: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariablesExtensions.AddEnvironmentVariables(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder)'.
> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

I am using **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration Verision-7.0.0**

Comment: Please share your configuration file.

Comment: Please share the .csproj file.

Answer (score 1):

When using .Net 6, please use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 6.0.x. So downgrade to 6.0.1. Same goes for other NuGet packages, such as Microsoft.Extensions.Logging - use version 6.0.x, not 7.0.x.